# Python : 2 sockets, sending from A to B and from B to A

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I've been working on this for 2 days and still I do not manage to get it to work properly.

I wanted to write an application that uses 2 sockets with a medium in the middle

This medium is this script that should read from socketA and write to SocketB and read from SocketB and write to SocketA.

However it seems I can not nail it.

My script when running accepts connections, but it will not allow me to input something on the telnet screen.

I am using 2 shared lists between the sockets to pass data.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys
    import arduinoReadThread
    import arduinoWriteThread
    import socket
    import thread



    bolt = 0
    socketArray=list()
    HOST =""
    HOST2=""
    PORT1 =50115
    PORT2 =50125



    s1=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ) #create an INET, STREAMing socket
    s1.bind((HOST,PORT1)) #bind to that port
    s1.listen(2) #listen for user input and accept 1 connection at a time.
    socketArray.append(s1)
    s2=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ) #create an INET, STREAMing socket
    s2.bind((HOST2,PORT2)) #bind to that port
    s2.listen(2) #listen for user input and accept 1 connection at a time.
    socketArray.append(s2)
    print "sockets set up"

    s1ToWriteList = list()


    s2ToWriteList = list()


    def socketFunctionWrite1():
            while(bolt == 0):
                client, address = s1.accept()

                print "Writing connections"
                if len(s1ToWriteList) > 0:
                    client.send(s1ToWriteList.pop(0))


    def socketFunctionRead1():
            while(bolt == 0):
                client2, address = s2.accept()

                f = client2.recv(1024)

                print "reading connection"
                s1ToWriteList.append(f)
                print len(s1ToWriteList)

    def socketFunctionWrite2():
            while(bolt == 0):
                client2, address = s2.accept()
                print "Writing connections"
                if len(s2ToWriteList) > 0:
                    client2.send(s2ToWriteList.pop(0))



    def socketFunctionRead2():
            while(bolt == 0):
                client, address = s1.accept()
                f = client.recv(1024)
            print "reading connection"
            s2ToWriteList.append(f)
            print len(s2ToWriteList)




def shutDown():
        test = raw_input("Quit ?")
        if(test =="y"):
            bolt = 1
        else:
            shutDown()

def spreadSockets():


        thread.start_new_thread(socketFunctionRead1,())
        print "launch 1"
        thread.start_new_thread(socketFunctionRead2,())
        print "launch 2"
        thread.start_new_thread(socketFunctionWrite1,())
        print "launch 3"
        thread.start_new_thread(socketFunctionWrite2,())

        print "launch 4"




spreadSockets()
while(True):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used your exact code and it worked for me.  I think what you might be doing wrong is telnet'ing to the wrong IP.  Dont use 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1, you need to use the actual (internal) IP of your box.

If on linux, you can see if with `ifconfig -a`, or `ipconfig /all` on windows.

Running your code exactly, no modification (except for removing the 2 unknown imports at the top):

Launched script:

```
[ 15:01 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/python ]$ ./sock.py
sockets set up
launch 1
launch 2
launch 3
launch 4
Writing connections
Writing connections
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sock.py", line 93, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Then telnet'd:

```
[ 15:01 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ telnet 10.10.1.11 50115
Trying 10.10.1.11...
Connected to 10.10.1.11.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello, World!
Hello 2
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
[ 15:02 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ telnet 10.10.1.11 50125
Trying 10.10.1.11...
Connected to 10.10.1.11.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello 50125!
Hi!
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
[ 15:02 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$
```

My internal interface config (`inet addr:10.10.1.11`):

```
[ 15:07 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/python ]$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**
          inet addr:10.10.1.11  Bcast:10.10.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...
```

Comment: @L make sure not to use localhost, as sockets usually only work when you connect to them via a real IP bound to an eth iface.

Comment: Also, change this: `while(True): pass` to this: `while(True): time.sleep(0.25)` so that your cpu doesnt explode into fiery molten hardware.

Comment: mmm I cant get the input I provide on interface A one to get displayed on interface B. I type test in window one press enter, but I do not get any ouput on my second screen

Comment: @Lucas When I get to work in a few minutes I'll post an example.

Comment: @LucasKauffman Good question btw.  Gonna steal, I mean use this code =D.